# Server and client side of sending an e-mail with SMTP protocol

Tags: smtp

I want to write both client and server sides of sending an e-mail also I should attend to the standard format of SMTP protocol which is specified in RFC 821.

Would you please help and guide me that how can I start it?

Comment: No, we're not interested in doing your homework for you.  But if you get stuck in a particular spot and have an SSCCE, holler.  http://sscce.org/

Comment: Your question is too broad. Also RFC821 is long ago supersed by RFC5321, so in any case if SMTP if of your interest you should start by reading the RFC from head to toe.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you reinvent the wheel? There are many implementations for both sides that do a very good job and are well tested.

What feature do you miss in let's say Postfix (server) and Outlook (client)?

If you still want to start, ask yourself

- how to create TCP Sockets and read/write to them
- how to do connection and thread pooling
- how to implement a state machine
- what are you doing with related topics? (SPF, DKIM, mbox storage, Maildir storage)
- what are you going to use for user authentication and authorization
- (... enter hundreds of other things here ...)